# Sencha Command Crash

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Current Projet is Prototype
CarboneNeutreApp is no more, it doesn't even exist anymore.

How can i resolve this problem?

[image: PRoblem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a hidden `.sencha` directory in generated projects, that's probably what you've missed.

**Delete the whole directory** (flags: `r`=recursive, `f`=force may be needed for the hidden directory):

```
rm -rf /Users/guillaumecharron/Sites/Prototype
```

Then your script should work again.

Comment: Thank you! I will be checking on that tomorrow!

Comment: Need your help again,  The command you wrote delete entirely my project. next the hidden .sencha directory doesn't exist in my app?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The hidden directory is `/Users/guillaumecharron/Sites/Prototype/.sencha`. You can try to delete only this directory, I don't know if that will work. The hidden directory will be generated again by the command you're running (`sencha ... generate app ...`).

Comment: Actually, i'm not running naything by myself, its architect who's doing it :S

Comment: Okay found my problem, you were 95% right, but I think the missing 5% was my fault.
There was a .sencha directory in Sites folders and not in my Prototype folder which was somehow there and confusing sencha CMD. Now it's gone and everything works. Thanks alot!!!!!